# How to make a PDF file upload instantly in an iPad application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am working on an iPad application. I have included some pdf files to it. All the PDFs work fine. Only thing is that the PDFs take 2-3 seconds to upload on the screen and there is one PDF which is taking about 1 min to upload. The average size of pdf file is 1.5 MB and all files are local. Is it happening because of the size of PDFs? Is there a way by which PDF could upload instantly?

Comment: Have a look at FlipReader in https://github.com/epatel/EPGLTransitionView which render one pdf page at a time. Maybe that is faster for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say 'upload', I think you mean 'load into RAM' based on the wording of your question. I've assumed that in this answer.

Instantly, certainly not, very little happens instantly. Faster, perhaps.

Is it possible for you to load only part of the PDF and display that, then, as the user is reading that part, load other parts.

Alternatively, when do you show the user the PDF? You could preload it at the start and then by the time the user comes to view it, some or all of the document will have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to draw the PDFs? You will likely do better using `CGContextDrawPDFPage` than just dumping an entire multi-page PDF into a UIWebView.